# Change foreground color of a layout programmatically

Tags: android

I want to change the foreground color of a linearlayout.
This is my code:`layout.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.svbackclr)));`
But this call require minimum api level 23.So how to do the same on pre 23 api.

Answer (score 14):

As @Gaurav suggested **FrameLayout** you can use the forground color by programatically in the following way

```
int color = R.color.black_trans_60;
frm.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, color)));
```

Comment: this is not working in Api 16 and as it requires api 23.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest to use `FrameLayout` 
In this you can use `setForeground()`

On any API level

Answer (score 4):

This is [a documentation bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186273) . `setForeground()` existed on `FrameLayout` from API Level 1; it is only on View as of API Level 23.

So it best to extend `FrameLayout`