# setForeground programmatically to hex colour

Tags: android, colordrawable

I have learned how to set an ImageView's foreground colour programmatically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520740/change-foreground-color-of-a-layout-programmatically), but this sets the colour to a value in the R.color resource:

```
int color = R.color.black_trans_60;
frm.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, color)));
```

However, I would like to directly set a String hex value to the colour --  is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use ColorDrawable with Color.parseColor("#000000"):

Comment: @ADM Yep, that solved my problem -- thanks.

Comment: Answer your own question then with solution. Thx .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ColorDrawable` with `Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")` like so:

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        holder.image.setForeground(cd);
```